# Application with UITableViewController becoming very unresponsive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've noticed that my entire app becomes very unresponsive after a little use. I opened up instruments and decided to do some tests, mostly on Memory and CPU Usage. I compared my app to the Twitter app as that uses both a `UITableView` and images in the tableView, much like my app. I'm completely new to instruments so had to use my very basic understanding of how iPhones work to figure out what everything indicates.

It seems that my memory usage is fine as both apps were surprisingly similar. My app after lots of use, very laggy by this stage: Real Memory: 55.63, Virtual: 152.03. Twitter: Real: 58.42, Virtual: 192.89. The Twitter app, despite using more memory was still really responsive (I wouldn't say super responsive, there were still some jumpy moments). With this closed, I moved on to the CPU.

Now this is where it get's weird. The Twitter app uses very small amounts of CPU (even though it's slightly more intensive than my app). When nothing is happening, the CPU usage drops to ~0%. It jumped up a couple of times, and this coincided with when the app became a little laggy. My app however is a humungous CPU hog! When nothing is happening my app uses 100% of the used CPU, which is about 80%-100%. In other words, when reading the bars on the Activity Monitor Instrument, the system load is not decreasing when the `UITableView` is idle, which is what the Twitter app was doing.

I therefore decided that this is why the app is becoming unresponsive/laggy. The problem is, I have no idea how to remedy this.

This is what I can think of:
- I do a whole load of asynchronous network requests. This however, doesn't explain why the CPU Usage stays up, as the requests are normally done within a second and the JSONs downloaded and parsed very soon after.
- I reload the TableView after every individual network request has been completed. However, as above, this is completed at the same time that the last JSON is downloaded, so there's no reason why this would cause the CPU usage to sky-rocket.
- Large amounts of calculations done in my cell configuration. However, same as the previous two, it doesn't explain much.

Even when I switch to a `UIViewController` the high load remains. The `UIViewController` is the starting view controller, and when the app first starts it has a load of 0% and remains at 0% indefinitely. The load only jumps up when the `UITableViewController` loads, and then it remains as described above. Therefore, this huge CPU usage has to be coming from the `UITableViewController`.

Has anyone got any ideas? Sorry for the massive wall of text. If you need me to post any code just ask and I will do.

Thanks for the help,
Regards, 
Mike

Comment: `UITableViewController` is the dumbest thing in the world, it hardly needs any CPU. It is used all over the place without causing much problems. Add some logging to your asynchronous code to see if it actually completes when you think that it does.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I use AFNetworking to do the asynchronous requests. In the completion block I do an NSLog. The requests are being done very quickly.

Comment: Run your app in the debugger and stop it at a random time when it's slow. Then check what all the different threads are doing. You might soon find something you don't expect and could be the culprit.

Comment: @Codo That's a good idea. Sadly however, I'm not particularly experienced so struggle with understanding all the gobbledygook the thread section throws out.

Comment: That's easy: Just hit the pause button in the debugger, then expand all threads to show the call stacks. If a thread's call stack shows only functions and methods of iOS, you can ignore it. But if it shows some methods of your app, then you want to click on the methods and investigate it: why is the method currently running? why is it stuck on this particular line? etc.

Comment: @Codo Perfect! I did just this and found one taking large percentages in instruments. I kept on following it further and further through the disclosure arrows until I found the method. I was accidentally calling an infinite loop on a removeFromSuperview method! That seems to have fixed it. CPU Usage drops to 0% when idle! Thanks for the help :)! If you want to write an official answer I'll accept it as the answer, but if not, I've marked up your two comments.

Comment: Glad, you solved it. I've added an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your app in the debugger and stop it at a random time when it's slow. Then check what all the different threads are doing. You might soon find something you don't expect and could be the culprit.

Just hit the pause button in the debugger, then expand all threads to show the call stacks. If a thread's call stack shows only functions and methods of iOS, you can ignore it. But if it shows some methods of your app, then you want to click on the methods and investigate it: why is the method currently running? why is it stuck on this particular line?

That's sort of the poor man's approach to performance debugging. The advanced approach is to use Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

> I do a whole load of asynchronous network requests. This however, doesn't explain why the CPU Usage stays up, as the requests are normally done within a second and the JSONs downloaded and parsed very soon after.

Usually they use the reverse approach: a well done app like Twitter uses a server that sends notifications to the app when something is updated.

Check out [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12).